# How to return a promise from a Firebase Firestore set() call?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is a followup to my question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100270/google-translate-api-and-firebase-firestore-are-killing-each-other`. Doug Stevenson said that I needed to return my functions. We watched his video `Learn JavaScript Promises (Pt. 3) for sequential and parallel work in Cloud Functions` a few hundred times...

I'm working with two functions. The first, a call to Google Translate, now returns a translation. The second function is a Firestore `set()` call, to write the translation to the database. The `set()` works if I don't do the Google Translate call, but together they crash. Specifically, if I call `Firebase set()` than the Google Translate function executes, we see `Result1`, and nothing further. In other words, calling the database stops to code from pushing a translation into the `translationArray`.

Here's my code now:

```js
exports.Google_EStranslateEN = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/Translation_Request_NOT').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {
        const { Translate } = require('@google-cloud/translate');

        // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
        const projectId = 'myProject-cd99d';

        // Instantiates a client
        const translate = new Translate({
            projectId: projectId,
        });

        // The text to translate
        const text = change.after.data().word;
        console.log(text);
        // The target language
        const target = 'en';

        let translationArray = []; // clear translation array

        const finalPromise = translate.translate(text, target)
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log("Result1: " + results);
                console.log(Array.isArray(results));
                console.log(results[0]);
                let translation = results[0];
                console.log(translation);
                return translation
            })
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log("Translation: " + results);
                translationArray.push(results);
                return translationArray
            })
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log("TranslationArray: " + translationArray);
                console.log("Result2: " + results);
                console.log("Text: " + text)
                return admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(text).collection('Translations').doc('English').set({
                    translationArray: results,
                    language: 'en',
                    longLanguage: 'English'
                });
            })
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log("Result3: " + results)
                console.log("Write succeeded!");
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    } // close if
    return 0;
}); // close oxfordPronunciationUS
```

The Firestore `set()` call returns nothing, and it kills the Google Translation call. Specifically, without the Firestore call the code executes all the way through, logging everything. With the Firestore call, neither function executes (Google Translate is never called) and nothing logs after "text."

I don't understand what `const finalPromise` does. It looks like an unused constant.

We read [Why are the Firebase API asynchronous?](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) and tried this code:

```js
var promise = admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(text).collection('Translations').doc('English').set({
    translationArray: translationArray,
    language: 'en',
    longLanguage: 'English'
});
promise.then(...)
```

That didn't help.

I tried switching to IBM Watson Translate, and the same thing is happening. Without the database call the translation function works perfectly. With the Firestore call it gets the translation, runs the `forEach`, and then stops when I try to push the word into the array. `translationsArray` doesn't log and nothing writes to the database.

```js
exports.IBM_EStranslateEN = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/Translation_Request_IBM').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {

        let word = change.after.data().word;
        let wordArray = [];
        wordArray.push(word);

        var LanguageTranslatorV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/language-translator/v3');

        var languageTranslator = new LanguageTranslatorV3({
            version: '2018-05-01',
            iam_apikey: 'swordfish',
            url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        var parameters = {
            "text": wordArray,
            "model_id": "es-en",
            "source": "es",
            "target": "en"
        };

        let translationsArray = [];

        languageTranslator.translate(
            parameters,
            function (err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error:', err);
                } else {
                    response.translations.forEach(function (translation) {
                        console.log(translation.translation);
                        translationsArray.push(translation.translation);
                    });
                    console.log(translationsArray);

                    admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(word).collection('Translations').doc('English').set({
                        translationsArray: translationsArray,
                        language: 'en',
                        longLanguage: 'English'
                    })
                        .then(function () {
                            console.log("Translations written to database.");
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        });

                }
            }
        );
    }
    return 0;
});
```

I also wrote the same cloud function calling the Oxford English Dictionary for the translation. This works perfectly, writing the translation to the database:

```js
exports.Oxford_EStranslateEN = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/Translation_Request').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {
        let word = change.after.data().word;
        let options = {
            uri: 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/es/' + change.after.data().word + '/translations%3Den', // translations=es
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'app_id': 'groucho',
                'app_key': 'swordfish'
            },
            json: true
        };
        let translationsArray = [];
        return rp(options)
            .then(function (wordObject) {
                wordObject.results.forEach(function (result) {
                    result.lexicalEntries.forEach(function (lexicalEntry) {
                        lexicalEntry.entries.forEach(function (entry) {
                            entry.senses.forEach(function (sense) {
                                if (sense.translations) {
                                    sense.translations.forEach(function (translation) {
                                        translationsArray.push(translation.text);
                                    });
                                } // close if
                                else {
                                    if (sense.subsenses) {
                                        sense.subsenses.forEach(function (subsense) {
                                            if (subsense.translations) {
                                                subsense.translations.forEach(function (translation) {
                                                    translationsArray.push(translation.text);
                                                }); // close forEach
                                            } // close if
                                            else {
                                                // console.log("No Translation");
                                            } // close else
                                        }); // close forEach
                                    } // close if
                                } // close else
                            }); // close forEach
                        }); // close forEach
                    }); // close forEach
                }); // close forEach
                translationsArray = [...new Set(translationsArray)]; // removes duplicates
                return admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(word).collection('Translations').doc('English').set({
                    translationsArray: translationsArray,
                    source: 'OED',
                    dateAdded: Date.now(), // timestamp
                    longLanguage: 'English',
                    shortLanguage: 'en',
                    word: word
                })
                    .then(function () {
                        // console.log("Document written.");
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log("Error writing document: ", error);
                    })
            })
            .then(function () {
                // console.log("Document written for Oxford_EStranslateEN.");
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error: " + error);
            });
    } // close if
    // return 0;
});
```

One difference is that I call the OED via an HTTP request, using `rp` (request-promise). I call `return rp(options)`. This clearly returns a promise, and the promise is explicitly returned. The problem seems to be that in the Google version I'm not returning the promise when I call Google Translate, and IBM Watson returns a callback, not a promise, and I don't return that.

Comment: `translationArray` is not in scope of the second `then` handler, should be `result` instead.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you mean by "it kills the Google Translation call".  When the promise from that call is resolved, and your code flows into the callback passed to then, the call is 100 % complete.  There is nothing left to kill.  If you're writing this code in Cloud Functions, please edit the question to show the entire function and not just its body.

Comment: If this is still unsolved, I'd like to clarify my comment above: Firestore doesn't like `undefined` values (they are not even compatible with JSON), but will throw an error. That is likely what you've experiencing, since `translationArray` is not defined in the scope it is used in.

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase JavaScript (Web) SDK `.set` method returns a promise, i.e., the promise is already there. See [Set A Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#set_a_document) online documentation.

> ```
> // Add a new document in collection "cities"
> db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
>     name: "Los Angeles",
>     state: "CA",
>     country: "USA"
> })
> .then(function() {
>     console.log("Document successfully written!");
> })
> .catch(function(error) {
>     console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
> });
> ```

You might find async/await easier to use (more intuitive).  In that scenario, you would do something like:

```
async function writeDocument(obj){
  var writeOperation = await db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set(obj);
  //now this code is reached after that async write
}
```

Comment: Doug Stevenson said that that doesn't return the promise, but instead creates more promises: "It's not sufficient to just call then() and catch() on every promise because then() and catch() both return yet another promise."  I don't understand what he's saying. His answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100270/google-translate-api-and-firebase-firestore-are-killing-each-other

Comment: [`.set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) returns a Promise

Comment: I think what Doug said was that I failed to return the promise from set(), and then I did .then and .catch, which created more promises that I failed to return. Does the phrase "return a promise" have two meanings? When you say that set() returns a promise, that isn't same as me coding "return myFunction()".

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

```js
exports.Google_EStranslateEN = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/Translation_Request_Google').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {
    // copied from https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');
    // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
    const projectId = 'myProject-cd99d';
    // Instantiates a client
    const translate = new Translate({
      projectId: projectId,
    });
    const word = change.after.data().word; // The word to translate
    const options = {
      from: 'es', // the source language
      to: 'en', // the target language
      format: 'text' // HTML vs. plain text
    };
    let translationArray = [];  // clear translation array
    return translate.translate(word, options)  // this return is critical
    .then(function(results) {
      let translation = results[0];
      translationArray.push(translation);
      admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(word).collection('Translations').doc('English').set({
        translationArray: translationArray,
        language: 'en',
        longLanguage: 'English'
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Write succeeded!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  } // close if
});
```

The key was to return the translate function:

```js
    return translate.translate(word, options)
```

The cloud function also runs faster.

Doug Stevenson answered [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100270/google-translate-api-and-firebase-firestore-are-killing-each-other):

> You're not returning a promise that's resolved when all the async work
>   is complete. If you don't do that, Cloud Functions assumes that all
>   your work is complete, and will clamp down on all resources, and any
>   pending work will be shut down.
>
> The promise returned by `translate.translate().then().catch()` is being
>   ignored. Your nested call to `admin.firestore()...set()` has a similar
>   problem. It's not sufficient to just call `then()` and `catch()` on every
>   promise because `then()` and `catch()` both return yet another promise.

It seems like the phrase "return a promise" is being used in two ways here. Saying that `translate.translate()` returns a promise is different from saying that I need to return a promise by coding `return translate.translate()`. Perhaps it would have been clearer if Doug had said to "return the function" instead of "return a promise"?

I'm also not clear on whether I need to return this function:

```
return admin.firestore()...set({
```

It works the same with or without the `return`.