# Google Cloud Function won't write to Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My Google Cloud Function gets an audio file from IBM Watson Text-to-Speech, saves it to Firebase Storage, and gets the signed download URL. Sometimes it will write the download URL to Firestore. Most of the time it won't. Here's the code:

```js
exports.IBM_T2S = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}/Spanish/IBM_T2S_Request').onUpdate((change) => {
  if (change.after.data().word != undefined) {
    // get requested word
    let word = change.after.data().word;
    console.log(word);
    let wordFileType = word + '.mp3';

    var synthesizeParams = {
      text: word,
      accept: 'audio/mpeg',
      voice: 'es-LA_SofiaVoice' // "es-ES_LauraVoice", "es-ES_EnriqueVoice", "es-US_SofiaVoice",
    };

    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket('myApp.appspot.com');
    const file = bucket.file('Audio/Spanish/Latin_America/' + wordFileType);

    var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');

    var textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
      username: 'groucho',
      password: 'swordfish',
      url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
    });

    const options = { // construct the file to write
      metadata: {
        contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
        metadata: {
          source: 'IBM Watson Text-to-Speech',
          languageCode: 'es-LA',
          gender: 'Female'
        }
      }
    };

    var config = {
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-17-2025'
    };

    return textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams).on('error', function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }).pipe(file.createWriteStream(options))
    .on('error', function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    })
    .on('finish', function() {
      console.log("Audio file written to Storage.");
      // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase
      file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '03-17-2025'
      })
      .then(function(signedUrls) {
        console.log(signedUrls[0]);
        console.log("Word is now: " + word);

        // Problem is here
        return admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(word).collection('Pronunciations').doc('Latin_America').update({
          audioFile: signedUrls[0]
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Download URL written to database, IBM Latin American, update.");
          return 0;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
          return 0;
        });
        // *****

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        return 0;
      });
    }); // close on
  } else {
    console.error("Error.");
    return 0;
  }
});
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100270/google-translate-api-and-firebase-firestore-are-killing-each-other) Doug Stevenson said

> You're not returning a promise that's resolved when all the async work
>   is complete. If you don't do that, Cloud Functions assumes that all
>   your work is complete, and will clamp down on all resources, and any
>   pending work will be shut down.
>
> The promise returned by translate.translate().then().catch() is being
>   ignored. Your nested call to admin.firestore()...set() has a similar
>   problem. It's not sufficient to just call then() and catch() on every
>   promise because then() and catch() both return yet another promise.

I don't understand what/where to return. The first async call

```js
return textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams).on('error', function(error) {
```

has to be returned to prevent the error `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value`. I.e., the cloud function finishes executing before the async functions come back, so you need a `return` before the first async function.

There might be a problem in that IBM Watson returns callbacks, not promises.

I return the last async function, as Doug Stevenson said to:

```js
  return admin.firestore().collection('Dictionaries').doc('Spanish').collection('Words').doc(word).collection('Pronunciations').doc('Latin_America').update({
          audioFile: signedUrls[0]
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Download URL written to database, IBM Latin American, update.");
          return 0;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
          return 0;
        });
```

In other words, I return the first async function and the last async function. That doesn't feel right. Is there documentation explaining where returns belong in Google Cloud Functions?

I also put `return 0;` into the catches, so that the cloud functions closes even when there's an error.

The cloud function usually stops at `"Audio file written to Storage."` Sometimes it goes on to log the download URL, and sometimes it writes the download URL to Firestore. Why does it sometimes write to Firestore and sometimes not?

Comment: It looks like you're assuming `on()` returns a promise.  Does it?  I suspect not.

Comment: Yes, IBM Watson returns callbacks, not promises. I was surprised that the error message "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" stopped when I returned the IBM Watson textToSpeech.synthesize function, as it doesn't return a promise or a value (it creates a stream). Your video doesn't cover callbacks.

Comment: Most modern APIs use promises, or let you choose between the two.  You can convert a callback to a Promise yourself.